# No reconoce mi tipo de variable DateTime en mi entidad

Tags: java, sql-server, webservice, spring-boot

estoy tratando de hacer un crud en spring , pero tengo problemas con listar mi entidad , no reconoce el tipo de variable DateTime en java , le puse LocalDateTime pero igual me regresa error , intenté colocando esta anotación JsonFormat y dandole forma del DateTime pero igual me lanza error y no lo reconoce ¿Cómo puedo dar Tipo de variable DateTime en java? en mi bd esta con DateTime y quiero que me reconozca la hora también en un solo campo

esta es mi entidad

```
package com.ebim.ClientesSpring.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape;
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",shape= Shape.STRING)
    private String createAt;
    private String email;
    
    public Cliente() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public Cliente(String nombre, String apellido, String createAt, String email) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.createAt = createAt;
        this.email = email;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }
    public void setCreateAt(String createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

este es mi controller

```
package com.ebim.ClientesSpring.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ebim.ClientesSpring.models.Cliente;
import com.ebim.ClientesSpring.serviceImpl.ClienteServiceImpl;

@CrossOrigin(origins= {"http://localhost:4200"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/cliente")
public class ClienteRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteServiceImpl _cliClienteServiceImpl;
    
    @GetMapping("/listadeClientes")
    public List<Cliente> listaCliente(){
        return _cliClienteServiceImpl.listarCliente();
    }
}
```

esta es mi tabla de bd

```
create database clientes

use clientes

create table cliente(
id int primary key identity (1,1),
nombre nvarchar(100),
apellido nvarchar (100),
createAt datetime ,
email nvarchar(200)
);
```

este es el error, es mas largo pero solo lo primero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está diciendo que la columna *create_at* no existe... lo cual tiene sentido porque en tu tabla le llamaste *createAt*. Si no me equivoco, spring cambia los nombres de camelCase a snake_case en la base de datos, lo cual significa que efectivamente está buscando una columna llamada `createAt` para tu campo `createAt`. Renombra la columna en tu base de datos o especifica con una anotación el nombre *correcto*.

Comment: @Benito-B y cual seria el tipo de dato que le daría createAt? localDateTime? , en mi bd debe ser DateTime, pero en spring que tipo de debe ser?